# AWS Redshift Posix pattern matching

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm quering a Redshift cluster using jdbc. The query has a single parameter:

```
select * from table_name bc where bc.column_name ~ ? limit 10
```

I'm suppling the parameter using

```
stmt.setString(1, "expected_value");
```

The query execution fails with and exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: The pattern must be a valid UTF-8 literal character expression
  Detail: 
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  The pattern must be a valid UTF-8 literal character expression
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     496280
  location:  cgx_impl.cpp:1902
  process:   padbmaster [pid=4192]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Executing a query without a parameter works fine:

```
select * from table_name bc where bc.column_name 'expected_value' ? limit 10
```

Any ideas what might cause the exception?

Comment: What 'expected_value' are you putting there? The problem seems related to the pattern provided. Are you using special character? I am able to run this on my redshift instance

Comment: a string, specifically "BestSellersWording"

Comment: What jdbc version are you using?

Comment: postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar

Comment: I guess you tried your statement on a psql shell and it worked, right? I would suggest trying another version, i am using 9.2-1004-jdbc41 when working with redshift.

Comment: Works from psql, doesn't with other jdbc driver versions. It sounds like a support request to Amazon is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Amazon Redshift JDBC Driver:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html